# Neo4j enterprise backup Windows 7

Tags: windows, neo4j, backup

I'm trying to run an Neo4j-database online-backup. I am using a Windows 7-machine and Neo4j enterprise 2.0.1.

I'm pretty new to all that database stuff, so I need pretty precise advice.

So far I have tried various steps to run the backup:

1. I created a clear directory for the backup (`C:\Users\Tobi\Desktop\neo_backup`)
2. I typed the following statement into the Neo4j command box: `./neo4j-backup -from single://localhost:7474 -to C:\Users\Tobi\Desktop\neo_backup`.

But, despite the red help box dropping down, nothing happens. I also tried some slightly different statements (i.e. using the IP-address etc.)

What am I doing wrong? Could someone give me some advice?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked out pretty well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run this from your **Windows command line**, execute `cmd` from the start menu, navigate (`cd c:\your\path\to\neo`) to the Neo4j installation directory and run it from there.

Also I think at least on Windows it's called Neo4jBackup.bat (but I'm not sure, having no Windows)